# C++ templates: How to conditionally delete values by std::is_pointer

Tags: c++, templates

In the destructor of a general container I did, I try to delete the elements if they are pointer, so I tried below. But when I tested with T=double, the compiler showed error message that delete must be followed by pointer. How can I do this properly?

```
template<class T> static void deleteIfPointer(T t)
{

    if(std::is_pointer<T>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "is pointer" << std::endl;
        delete t;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "not pointer" << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: it happens because the compiler has to compile the line `delete t` regardless of what the condition of the `if` is about to be. If you   comment that line out, your code will compile just fine and gives the result as expected. I would accept the answer of Piotr S.

Comment: My two cents: I wouldn't do this (because it is very weird ownership) and just have the container hold std::unique_ptrs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template <class T>
static void deleteIfPointer(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << "not pointer" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
static void deleteIfPointer(T* t)
//                           ^
{
    std::cout << "is pointer" << std::endl;
    delete t;
}
```

Comment: + 1 for not over-complicating things.

Comment: Pass by `T const &` (and `T const *`) BTW.

Comment: @Nawaz `T const &` I agree. `T const *` is unnecessary - `T` can be deduced to a `const U` just fine.

Comment: @Angew: Being explicit is better than implicit. Explicit is an "announcement" for the world.

Comment: @Nawaz except that it will break if you try to pass a pointer to non-const, and select the non-pointer overload instead.

Comment: @T.C.: Non-const can convert into const.

Comment: @Nawaz But wouldn't that conversion be "more expensive," making that overload the less preferred one? gcc [says it would](http://ideone.com/qanzQa).

Comment: @Nawaz You have an exact match (`T const &` with `T` being the pointer's type) vs a qualification conversion. The first wins.

Comment: @Angew: I'm surprised :|. No matter how much I explore this language, it always surprises me! Thanks.